# Will my tobacco plant survive indoors under this grow light?

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, watering, compost, light

[image: Two pots of soil in saucers under a pink grow light]

Hi I'm trying to grow tobacco indoors but they have not come up yet. I'm currently on day 2. I'm using a clip on 40w LED grow light. Will this be enough for them to grow? I have a link of the model [on Amazon.com](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Garpsen-360%C2%B0Adjustable-Gooseneck-Seedlings-Succulents/dp/B081CVDS1B/ref=sr_1_26?crid=ZRLS47TGGPKJ&keywords=Clip%20on%20grow%20light&qid=1669070797&sprefix=clip%20on%20grow%20light%2Caps%2C570&sr=8-26)

I'm using Levingtons peat free compost and miracle grow. They are kept in a propagator when they receive their darkness.

If anyone could help that would be great! Really want to get into indoor tobacco growing! :)

Answer (score 2):

Tobacco (ornamental or otherwise) is not the easiest plant to germinate; I've had some issues with ornamental tobacco in the past, probably due to not giving the seeds enough light. It's very important that the seeds not be buried in the soilless mix. If you're only on Day 2 of germination, you have another 5-12 days to wait to see if your attempt is successful.

As for the light, I think it may be okay for young seedlings (you'll have to lower it to about 2"/5cm from the pots), but it doesn't look nearly large enough for the plants as they grow. Remember, smoking tobacco is a huge plant and can grow up to 3ft/1m wide and 6ft/2m high. I recommend looking into light setups for cannabis growers, as some strains of cannabis can reach the same proportions as tobacco. What you'll need also depends on the number of tobacco plants you'll be growing.

[This site](https://www.trueleafmarket.com/pages/how-to-start-tobacco-seeds) gives some great information on growing smoking tobacco, including growing in pots, harvesting, and curing. Nothing on lighting, though. Take especial note of the differences in soils used for wrapper vs. fill tobaccos. You will need to switch from your germination soilless mix to a specialty mix probably soon after your seedlings get their second or third set of true leaves.